# How to use appcompat-v7 with android API 19

Tags: java, android, compatibility, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

All is in the questioin

I have a module with this graddle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    compileOptions.encoding "ISO-8859-1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

When I change "compileSdkVersion" to 19 => I get 100+ errors about ressources not found :

Example :

```
    Error:(9, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
```

Comment: try this   `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'`

Comment: targetSdkVersion shouldn't be 8, that's really realy bad.

Comment: This is a library module, i could get ride of targetSdkVersion i think

Comment: I personally am using M D answer since a long time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

of course you are getting these errors in API<21, because `android:TextAppearance.Material` and others (Material) were introduced in API 21. AppCompat is porting resources, but they are used without `android:` prefix (I can't check at this moment if these you are using also, but probably yes). If you compile your app with API 21 and run on lower API device crashes will occur also

`android:` prefix refer to built-in params, which should be in all versions of supported APIs (minSDK). Material isn't present in pre-API21 systems

Comment: do you mean in other words our minsdk should be at least API 21?

Comment: no, use min sdk version which you want to support. but if you want to use any new method/class/style (as above) from newer SDK keep in mind that app on devices with older Android version (like this oldest supported minSdk) might throw `Exception` or simply omit these lines (e.g. attrs in XML files). above question is about `AppCompat` library, which brings to your app some methods/classes/styles from newer sdk, so e.g. new styles (Material, partialy) might be used also in older systems (e.g. ICS), but note that they have different naming which is not interfering with original names

Answer (score 0):

Check the compileSdkVersion in build.gradle

eg.

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
        //jumboMode true
    }
}
```

If you keep the latest, shouldnt give you headaches. Reason this happens is if there are multiple R files generated for the same library.